# How to isolate 1 MongoDB config server

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I need to preform a rolling upgrade on my MongoDB.
I've been all over the Mongo documentation and I can't find a solution to my problem (if there is one)
Here's a simple sketch of the Architecture:

[image: Arq]

I have two Sites (A and B) (telecommunications site, not website).
When I'm executing a rolling upgrade in one site I need to upgrade everything associated to it.

I place my site B in contingency (there are no requests from outside arriving to that Site) and I start upgrading everything, but when I get to the config server I find a problem.

Config servers are always in sync, and this can't happen because all communication with the outside must be terminated.

Is there a way to isolate the config server on that site? (I know they're replicated)
I hope you guys understand my question, is basically how to preform a config server rolling upgrade in multi-host environment without completely stopping all 3 config servers (stopping both sites is not a valid solution)

Will upgrading my config server will have any impact in my service? (in the other site)

Can I shut down 1 config server, upgrade and restart it?

thanks

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/#upgrade-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply stop one config server, upgrade and restart it. That is one of the reasons why there are three: even when taking down one, there are two others to *read* from, so one might fail.

A few things to keep in mind, though:

- When one config server is down, the cluster meta data is read only: no chunk splits or migrations during that time. So in order to prevent JumboChunks, you better hurry a bit.
- Talking of JumboChunks: you should check your cluster for them after update
- As for the order: Start with the last server in your configdb string, finish with the first
- Always, *Always*, ***ALWAYS*** read the migration guide of the version you are updating to